# onkeyup vs onkeypress - Evento al pulsar la tecla Space Javascript

Tags: javascript, onkeypress, onkeyup

`onkeyup` para comprobar cuando levantemos la tecla, en lugar `onkeypress` valora el dato al pulsar la tecla.

El problema que tengo es que me funciona mi funcionalidad con `onkeyup` pero con `onkeypress` no funciona. 
Explico.

Tengo un `evento` para comprobar tecla a tecla si existe o no el **email** que introducimos en un campo "`input`" en la base de datos.

**Fichero comprobar_email.php:**

```
<?php
    //Cabecera para indicar que vamos a enviar datos JSON y que no haga caché de los datos.
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

    //Función que comprueba si existe o no un email.
    function mailExists($email) {
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=osmarrural", "root", "root");
        $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $sql = "SELECT count(idemail) AS total FROM clientes WHERE idemail ='$email'";
        $datos = $conexion->query($sql);
        $registro = $datos->fetch();
        return $registro["total"];
    }

    //Si existe la variable/campo "idemail"...
    if(isset($_REQUEST["idemail"])){
        $respuesta = mailExists($_REQUEST["idemail"]);
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }else{
        $respuesta = -1;
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
?>
```

**Función comprobar_email:**

```
function comprobar_email(e){
    var tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    //Permitimos el acceso a una tecla "Space".
    if (tecla == 32){
        return false;
    }

    //Guardamos en una variable el valor del campo cuyo ID es "email".
    var caja_email = $("#email").val();
    //Llamamos por get/post al fichero que hemos creado para comprobar_email;
    $.get("comprobar_email.php", {idemail:caja_email}, function(resultado){
        //Si resultado==1, el email existe... color de fondo rojo y deshabilitar botón.
        if(resultado==1){
            $("#email").css({backgroundColor: '#EA0D0D'});
            $('#registrar').hide();
        }else{
            //Si resultado!=1, el email NO existe... color de fondo verde y habilitar botón.
            $("#email").css({backgroundColor: '#1EEA02'});
            $('#registrar').show();
        }
    });
}
```

**Código que sí funciona:**

```
<input type="text" name="idemail" id="email" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="return comprobar_email(event);">
```

**Código que no funciona:**

```
 <input type="text" name="idemail" id="email" placeholder="Email" onkeypress="return comprobar_email(event);">
```

El problema que con `onkeyup` me permite escribir "**space**" cuando debería oprimirla. Entonces si lo cambio a `onkeypress`, entonces "**space**" sí lo oprime, pero necesito insertar un caracter más de la cuenta cuando escribo el **email** para comprobar si existe o no.
Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: A que te refieres con un caracter más de la cuenta?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Que para comprobar que la función comprobar_email funciona debo pulsar una tecla más. Explico. Si "a@msn.com" existe, y en el campo email ingresa el usuario "a@msn.com" dice que está disponible (cuando no lo está) y si ingresa "a@msn.coma" dice que no está disponible.

Comment: Vamos que debe ser onkeyup pero me acepta la tecla space cuando la debe denegar.

Comment: El problema es que con keyup no te va a dar, si retornas false después de haber soltado la tecla entonces no estarás haciendo nada por eso te deja ingresar el espacio, prueba entonces con onkeydown a ver que tal

Comment: Con onkeydown me prohíbe la tecla "space" pero volvemos al anterior problema, que necesito un carácter más... para comprobar la validez.

Comment: [Mira esto de stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

Comment: El aporte está bien pero es un problema concreto @LuisFernando

Comment: Pruebe dejando el `onkeyup`. Pero el `if` de su `function` cámbielo por `(tecla !== 32)` y globalicelo con toda la función. que quede: "si la tecla oprimida no es espacio, ejecute..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tratas de hacer todo a la vez cuando son cosas que deberían ejecutarse en diferente momento.

Por un lado quieres que, antes de que se escriba el carácter, se compruebe si el carácter es válido.

Por otro lado quieres que, una vez que se haya escrito el carácter, se compruebe si el email introducido existe.

La solución es obvia: separar el código y ejecutar cada función en diferente evento:

En el evento `keypress` compruebas si la tecla pulsada se corresponde con un carácter válido y, si no es así, lo anulas.

En el evento `keyup` compruebas que el email introducido es válido.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando. He utilizado jQuery para registrar los controladores de eventos, y he sobrescrito el método `get` de jQuery para que, en lugar de hacer la petición ajax, devuelva un resultado de que el email existe únicamente para `'a@msn.com'`:

```js
function checkValidKey(e){
  var tecla = document.all ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  return tecla !== 32;
}
function comprobar_email(e){
    //Guardamos en una variable el valor del campo cuyo ID es "email".
    var caja_email = $("#email").val();
    //Llamamos por get/post al fichero que hemos creado para comprobar_email;
    $.get("comprobar_email.php", {idemail:caja_email}, function(resultado){
        //Si resultado==1, el email existe... color de fondo rojo y deshabilitar botón.
        if(resultado==1){
            $("#email").css({backgroundColor: '#EA0D0D'});
            $('#registrar').hide();
        }else{
            //Si resultado!=1, el email NO existe... color de fondo verde y habilitar botón.
            $("#email").css({backgroundColor: '#1EEA02'});
            $('#registrar').show();
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
  // Registro controladores de eventos
  $('#email').on('keyup', comprobar_email);
  $('#email').on('keypress', checkValidKey);
  // Reemplazar llamada ajax
  // Únicamente devuelve que existe con 'a@msn.com'
  $.get = function(url, data, callback){
    callback(data.idemail === 'a@msn.com'?1:0);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text" name="idemail" id="email" placeholder="Email">
 
 <button id="registrar">Registrar</button>
```

Comment: En mi caso obtengo los emails de una consulta a la base de datos en lugar de "a@msn.com", ¿cómo sería trasladado a mi código?

Comment: Simplemente deberías eliminar la parte que reemplaza la llamada ajax

Comment: Si elimino la parte de Ajax, ¿entonces cómo hace la comprobación? Edité la respuesta... Añadí el código completo.

Comment: Me refiero a eliminar el código que he utilizado para evitar que se realice tu llamada Ajax, el `$.get = function(url, data, callback) { ..... };`. De esta forma debería volver a funcionar tu llamada a `comprobar_email.php`

Comment: Aún así no me funciona. He borrado el $.get y tampoco...

Comment: Si antes te funcionaba con `onkeyup` debería seguir funcionándote igual. Ten en cuenta que lo único que he hecho es sacar la comprobación de espacios a otra función que se llama en el `onkeypress`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70916/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-asier-villanueva).